# What is the color of a "Info" view in IPhone's address?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is the color of "Info" view of a contact info in IPhone? When you're viewing the details of a contract, you can observe that the background color with white lines in the contact's "Info" view. If I want to set the same color to my UIViewController how can I set the same?

And one more, when you're viewing a contract's or a call's info (if it is a call and that caller is not stored in your address book or if it is contact and there is no image set for that contact) you can observe that the default image. How can I do the same. My requirement is to draw a "default image" and also set the same background color of "Info" view's in my UIViewController.

Regards,
Prathap.

Comment: I don't have my mac at work but it's probably easier to launch the emulator or the iPhone connected to the Mac, screenshot and then use GIMP or something like that to pull out the `rgba` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]`. So the result code will be like that

> ```
> [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
> ```

Comment: arrgh... you can mark this question as answered, so other peoples with the same problem will find an answer faster....